# Kubuntu 14.04 LTS corrupted, how to recover? Also want an upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu

Linuhackz here. I was using my desktop as usual. One day it automatically logged out by itself and when i try to log in, it goes back to the login window. Again and again I have to log in and the wallpaper doesn't even show properly! I cannot fix this problem. I am running Ubuntu Unity 14.04 along with KDE and GNOME. As I can't fix this problem, I want to upgrade it. Along with that I will do a recovery. How do I do both?

-Linuhackz

EDIT: This also has a system program problem that is there. I think this has something to do with the desktop. Should I login to the terminal? And this has nothing to do with graphics.

-L.Hz.

Comment: While you're on the login screen, press CTRL+ALT+F1. It'll get you to a terminal screen. Enter your username and your password, then you'll be in a shell with your user. Try running `journalctl -xe` on it so that we can see the error?

Comment: If you want to upgrade, i advise you to make a bootable usb, backup your data and completely wipe your drive. doing dist-upgrade may work but is not recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)